# Stop page refreshing after back button pressed

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to stop a web page from refreshing when it is displayed after someone presses the back button?

My web page shows different information every time it is refreshed. I want it to show whatever it was showing before the user moved to another page.

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Use a [url hash](http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2011/10/must-know-url-hashtechniques-for-ajax-applications/) to track their current state in your page, then in your code make sure that hash refers to a specific state or content and just reload that content.  This method works very well for back buttons and bookmarks.

Comment: It depends on a whole lot of things too numerous to list here. With no information on how the site is even built, you're throwing darts at a board.

Comment: Not sure how much detail you need Brett? What I am hoping to find out is how a web page can affect whether or not it is refreshed after a back button press. It may well be that this is totally out of the control of the web page, or that there are things a web page can do. Even one or two examples of the things too numerous to mention might help.

Comment: Howard, it is not clear to me how a url hash can be used with the browser back button. Is this programmable from the web page?

Comment: @BillNoble - there are a few tricks (like meta tags) that rarely work, and if they do it's normally for only one version of a browser, so they are completely ineffective.  check out the link that I included with my previous comment.  It shows how the url hash can be used in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The contents of the window when the 'back' button is pressed is actually data your browser has cached so preventing 'back' is not going to help.

You could maybe use a hash though.

go to

```
stackoverflow.com
```

then go to

```
stackoverflow.com#foo
```

then go to

```
stackoverflow.com#foobar
```

If you hit the back button you'll notice the hash changes but the page does not refresh.

Sorry about the formatting. Blame SO!

Comment: But is it possible to affect what the back button on the browser does Shawn?

Comment: You can create an annoying confirmation dialog but that's about it. There is a good reason for this. You shouldn't change the default behavior of the browser itself you should be changing the way your code renders the page.

Comment: Imagine if such a thing were possible. It makes me sick just thinking about it haha. Web sites would hijack your browser all day long!

Comment: Yes I can see why it is a bad thing! Looks like there is no way to ensure my page looks as it should after a back, which is a shame.